# Will PNS in Production mode work only on jailbroken device

Tags: iphone, ios6, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, jailbreak

I have implemented APNS in development and for production mode we have created all the certificates the same way as in development mode. When testing on device using AdHoc build, APNS do not arrive.

I want to know whether the device has to be jailbroken for receiving APNS in production mode.

Comment: what you have set for `sandbox` at server side?

Comment: i have removed sandbox from URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adhoc builds receive push notifications sent to the production APNS server. The device doesn't have to be Jailbroken (I'm not even sure if push notifications work on Jailbroken devices).

You have to make sure you are using the production certificate, and that your application was built with an Adhoc provisioning profile.

Run your app with a debugger and check which method is called - `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` or `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:`. If the former, send the device token to your server (and delete the development device token from your server). If the latter, print the error delivered to this callback.